# Is there a way to have a PowerShell be executed automatically within a directory?

Tags: powershell

I have a situation and am hoping there is an easy way to get around it.

I have a folder, and inside this folder, there are 12 other sub-folders. Inside each of these sub-folders, there is PS script and 2 files being compared in the script. The 2 files are called using parameters in the script.

Is there a way to have all of the scripts run automatically? I'm assuming it would have to be another script that can then iterate through the subfolders?

If anymore information is needed or any other suggestions can be made, please let me know! Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could you please try to suggest some example folder structure and what code you have in place for comparison? Would help to provide you with valuable answer. Thanks

Comment: In the scripts, are the 2 files referenced by their absolute or relative paths?

Comment: When you say that you want the scripts to be run automatically, do you mean to call them each automatically when you manually run another PowerShell script? Or are you looking to have this run on a schedule or bound to an event of some sort (and run automatically without manually initiating the process)?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, you need to parts of codes:

1. Get-childitem -recursive , filter ps1
2. Foreach script , invoke-command.